# Validate ASP.NET membership Username and Password when IsApproved is false

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, membership-provider

How can I check if the password entered by the user matches the password stored in the database when the IsApproved value is FALSE?

What I hope to do is as follows...

1. User registers - details saved and IsApproved is set to false
2. User recieves welcome email with membership confiirmation link
3. User clicks link in email - IsApproved is set to True at this point
4. User can NOW login

Okay everyting is fine with all of the above and i dont percieve any problems.

Where I'm having issues is...

When the user attempts to login and his/her IsApproved flag is FALSE
I need to cross reference his/her password wih the one stored in DB
And thats where i'm stuck.

The idea was to cross check the password, and if the user entered VALID credentials then to show a message to the user to say ACTIVATE your membership by clicking in the email blah blah blah.

But even if the password entered matches, because I cannot check it in the code the ValidateUser function always returns false because IsApproved is set to false!

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

ALSO I dont actually need to see the password, so even if theres a sealed function I can call that simply confirms if the pasword matches thats fine too...

Below is my code block..

```
        Public Function ValidateUser(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByRef PwdMatches As Boolean, ByRef Approved As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IMembershipService.ValidateUser
    '
    Dim ThisMember As MembershipUser = Nothing
    Dim ThisResult As Boolean = Nothing
        '
        Approved = False
        ThisResult = False
        PwdMatches = False
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "Username")
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "Password")
        ElseIf _Provider.ValidateUser(Username, Password) Then
            ThisResult = True
        Else
            Try
                ThisMember = _Provider.GetUser(Username, False)
                Try
                    If (ThisMember Is Nothing) = False Then
                        Approved = ThisMember.IsApproved
                        Try
                          <!-- This is the point im stuck on -->
                            If Password_Matches_With_Password_In_Db Then
                                PwdMatches = True
                            Else
                                PwdMatches = False
                            End If
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            ThisResult = False
                        End Try
                    Else
                        ThisResult = False
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ThisResult = False
                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception
                ThisResult = False
            End Try
        End If
        Return ThisResult
        ThisMember = Nothing
        ThisResult = Nothing
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the `Membership GetPassword` method, passing `Nothing` in as the `passwordAnswer` parameter, which should just cause the password to be returned.

A disclaimer on this approach, however: we have implemented our own membership provider and SQL, and I don't have the original code to validate this against, so there may be something in the default provider that would prevent this approach, but it is worth trying.

EDIT:

In the case that the password is hashed, a possible solution to the problem is to perform a direct database query against the users table to get the state of the IsApproved flag. You could do this either before or after the call to GetUser, depending on how much you trust your end users (if you don't trust them, I would call it after in order to prevent someone from trying multiple users to see which are active).

Comment: Yes I believe the password is hashed so maybe that approach may not work, but i will give it a try later and see if it works, I'll keep you informed if it worked or not.

Comment: Ah, a hashed password would definitely present a problem. I have updated the answer with an additional idea.

Comment: Hiya Competent_tech, My code block above can assess if the IsApproved property is true or false, but its still doesnt account for the fact that if the password was typed incorrectly its still possible to get the value of IsApproved but it doesnt solve the issue of if the passowrd and username are correct but the isapproved is set to false in which case i wold like to advise the user to ACTIVATE their profileby clicking the link in the welcome email

Comment: I think you basically have two options: 1) you could pull the SqlMembership provider into your codebase and you would then be able to make any sort of change that you want like this (this is what we did) or 2) modify the get user stored procedure to always return IsApproved = True, then double-check it directly in code if the user's login is successful.

Answer (score 0):

- I think one way to do it create a table that stores user accounts pending for approval. When user registers, populate this table with the userID or userName or set some flags indicating users who account has not been activated and who mails have been sent. Check this table when user logs in, if exist or flag not set, display "Activate your account to user"
- Write a function that connects to the DB and use the userId to get the approval status from `Aspnet_Membership` table. The column name is `IsApproved` which is true or false

  `Dim user As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userName);
   Dim isApproved As Boolean = myMethodCheckIfUserIsApproved(user.ProviderUserKey); //userID`

Comment: Hiya CodingBiz, as per my code sample above, I can already get the ISAPPROVED value held inthe database, but i need to confirm the password was correct in order to tel the user to activate his/her password.... The idea being ... If password + Username MATCH those on FILE + IsApproved = False then Show message activate your membership...  

Where as... is user types incorrect password AND username is CORRECT, I can STILL get IsApproved value... BUT no point in showing activate membership profile if the password was incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE & ANSWER TO MY QUESTION

Hello everyone who replied to my question and thank you for your help,
It seems I was barking up the wrong tree by trying to validate the PASSWORD before trying to see if the account membership had been approved.

I have resolved the issue in a VERY SIMPLE WAY indeed.
This is how I did and I did not need to DIRECTLY interogate the database password field nor did i have to worry about hashing the password.

First of all I modified the default VALIDATELUSER call declaration....
in the SERVICES region of the ACCOUNTS MODEL
from...

```
Function ValidateUser(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
```

To...

```
Function ValidateUser(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByRef IsApproved As Boolean) As Boolean
```

This enabled me to call my newly modfied validation process also in the SERVICES region of the Accounts model where the ORGINIAL CODE was as follows...

```
Public Function ValidateUser(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean Implements IMembershipService.ValidateUser
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) Then Throw New ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName")
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) Then Throw New ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "password")
  Return _provider.ValidateUser(userName, password)
End Function
```

And the MODIFIED function which is now as follows...

```
Public Function ValidateUser(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByRef Approved As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IMembershipService.ValidateUser
  Dim ThisMember As MembershipUser = Nothing
  Dim ThisResult As Boolean = Nothing
  '
    Approved = False
    ThisResult = False
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) Then
      Throw New ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "Username")
    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password) Then
      Throw New ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "Password")
    ElseIf _Provider.ValidateUser(Username, Password) Then
      ThisResult = True
    Else
      ThisMember = _Provider.GetUser(Username, False)
      If (ThisMember Is Nothing) = False Then
        Approved = ThisMember.IsApproved
      End If
    End If
    Return ThisResult
    ThisMember = Nothing
    ThisResult = Nothing
  End Function
```

I'm much happier with this prcoedure than with messing about with direct manipulation of the DB and also hashing the password.

So in effect, it was more about the original sequence of processing being back to front....
IE.
Not (1)validate login credentials then (2)check if email confirmed? (via link in welcome message)
but rather...
(1)Email Confirmed then (2)validate login credentials

Comment: This looks like it still can't validate the user's credentials unless the isApproved field is set to 'true'. Have you found a way to validate credentials even if the isApproved field is set to 'false'? I'm in the exact same boat you were in with that question.